# Can I implement custom 'query' function on composer

Tags: hyperledger-composer

Can I implement custom 'query' function on composer? in my understanding, transaction processor is 'invoke' and cannot return data　
synchronously. how do i add query logic after getting Assets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Composer v0.12.2 exposes named queries as GET methods from the composer-rest-server. Simply define your business network queries using the Composer Query Language, start the composer-rest-server for your network and it will automatically generate the REST endpoints that execute your queries and return the results.

This is described in detail here:
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/queries.html

Comment: yes, I think so. I'd like to filter Asset List with query args.

Comment: @dan-selman is this exposed now? Is it possible to filter on our rest api to find a specific set of assets? I have been trying to find info on composer rest api filter and query since few days with no luck. Please help.